# android Room. how can I get the data class with columns returned by the query does not have the fields

Tags: android, android-room

I want to get my data class with **property** `isActivated`having default value `false` from the query

this is the target entity

```
@Entity(tableName = "MY_ENTITY")
data class MyEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "A") val a: Long = 0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "B") val b: String
)
```

here is the data class I want to get from query

```
data class MyDataClass(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "A") val a: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "B") val b: String,

    var isActivated: Boolean = false              // this is the problem I want to solve
)
```

this is query in room dao

```
@Query(SELECT A, B FROM MY_ENTITY)
fun getEntity(): List<MyDataClass>
```

**the property `isActivated` is in normal data class not in Room Entity data class**

error message is here

```
error: The columns returned by the query does not have the fields [isActivated] in MyDataClass
even though they are annotated as non-null or primitive. Columns returned by the query: [A, B]
public abstract java.lang.Object loadAllGroupVOs(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem myself but I don't know this is good idea.

I changed my query like below

from

```
@Query(SELECT A, B FROM MY_ENTITY)
fun getEntity(): List<MyDataClass>
```

to

```
@Query(SELECT A, B, 0 as IS_ACTIVATED FROM MY_ENTITY)
fun getEntity(): List<MyDataClass>
```

and data class have also changed into like this.

from

```
data class MyDataClass(
  @ColumnInfo(name = "A") val a: Long,
  @ColumnInfo(name = "B") val b: String,
    
  var isActivated: Boolean = false              // this is the problem I want to solve
)
```

to

```
data class MyDataClass(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "A") val a: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "B") val b: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = IS_ACTIVATED) var isActivated: Boolean = false
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can put @Ignore for isActivated if you don't want to use it like this :

```
data class MyDataClass(
  @ColumnInfo(name = "A") val a: Long,
  @ColumnInfo(name = "B") val b: String,
    
  @Ignore
  var isActivated: Boolean = false             
)
```